# @Override method does not override method from superclass in tutorial

Tags: java, selenium, overriding

I've recently taken on a new job and they are requiring me to get to grips with Java.

I'll be using Java and Selenium Webdriver to automate test cases etc.

To throw myself into the java/Webdriver world, I bought this [book](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/mastering-selenium-webdriver), Mastering Selenium Webdriver.

When going through the book we get to a section on making the tests run in parellel and I'm asked to create two new classes.

> DriverFactory.java and WebDriverThread.java

Once i've made all the changes and go to build, and run my tests with maven. using the following command in the cmdline.

> mvn clean install

I get the following error

> @Override method does not override method from superclass

I've had a google around and I'm not really sure how to fix the issue. The book is assuming some Java experience that I just don't have yet.

below are the two classes in full that I've since created.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;


public class WebDriverThread {

private WebDriver webDriver;

private final String operatingSystem =
        System.getProperty("os.name").toUpperCase();

private final String systemArchitecture =
        System.getProperty("os.arch");

public WebDriver getDriver() throws Exception {
    if (null == webDriver) {
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Current Operation System: " + operatingSystem);
        System.out.println("Current Architecture: " + systemArchitecture);
        System.out.println("Current Browser Selection: FireFox");
        System.out.println(" ");
        webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
    }

    return webDriver;
}

public void quitDriver() {
    if (null != webDriver) {
        webDriver.quit();
        webDriver = null;
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the second class created,

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

public class DriverFactory {

private static ThreadLocal<WebDriverThread> driverThread;

@BeforeSuite
public static void instantiateDriverObject() {
    driverThread = new ThreadLocal<WebDriverThread>() {
        @Override
        protected WebDriverThread InitialValue() {
            WebDriverThread webDriverThread =
                    new WebDriverThread();
            return webDriverThread;

        }
    };
}

public static WebDriver getDriver() throws Exception {
    return driverThread.get().getDriver();
}

@AfterMethod
public static void quitDriver() throws Exception {
    driverThread.get().quitDriver();
   }
}
```

The error is one the @Override line. I've read that it's something to do with not implementing a class from the class it's inheriting from?

I'm then calling the this all from this line in the actual test.

> WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getDriver();

I think i've tried to walk before I could crawl, but i thought getting this book would give me a jump up for the new job.

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `initialValue`, not `InitialValue`. No initial cap.

Comment: Thank you @teppic.

I thought I double checked all caps.